# i am not getting proper output in java using cmd .prompt

Tags: java, java-8

for large number of input the out put of the the last input is not displyed.
when i used to input 15 or more different input the output i get is one less than the given number of output . the output that is not displayed is the last output one.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();

    while(sc.hasNext())
    {

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
            if(x>=-pow(2,15) && x<pow(2,15))System.out.println("* short");
            if(x>=-(long)pow(2,31) && x<(long)pow(2,31))System.out.println("* int");
            if(x>=-(long)pow(2,63) && x<(long)pow(2,63))System.out.println("* long");

            //Complete the code
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide the full code. Being able to run it with no modifications makes it easier to help.

Comment: you are essentially skipping the first input by getting the nextInt() and then getting the next long in the first line of your try block.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think, that second line of your code should explain the missing number from the input. You read first number from input and then do nothing with it:

```
int t=sc.nextInt();
```

But there are more problems with your code.
Judging from casting to (long) you do in these lines:

```
        if(x>=-(long)pow(2,31) && x<(long)pow(2,31))System.out.println("* int");
        if(x>=-(long)pow(2,63) && x<(long)pow(2,63))System.out.println("* long");
```

I'm guessing that your `pow` function doesn't return `long`, but probably `int`. And maybe also calculatations you are doing inside `pow` functions are also done on integers. This will cause integer overflows and return incorrect results. You should change them to `long`.

Futhermore the last value you are trying to calculate - `pow(2,63)` - can`t fit even into`long`, so you can't calculate it. I suggect using Long.MAX_VALUE instead.

Comment: I’d rather bet that `pow` refers to `Math.pow`. So `pow(2,63)` might be outside the `long` value range, but `(long)pow(2,63)` will cut it down to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. A real issue is the difference between `-(long)pow(2,63)` and `(long)-pow(2,63)` and the general logic error of trying to check whether a value held in a `long` variable is possibly outside the `long` value range…